# unable to get installed software details of vm machine of azure using System.Management

Tags: c#, azure, azure-virtual-machine

My requirement is to get installed software details of vm machine of azure and store the details in db. but when I try to get the details using System.Management class I am getting the below error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)'

below is my sample code I am using to get the software details

```
 string SoftwareQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Product";
        ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();



            connection.Username = "bla bla";
            connection.Password = "Password";

        connection.EnablePrivileges = true;
        connection.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

        ManagementScope managementScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\xxxx.xxxx.cloudapp.azure.com:3389\root\CIMV2", connection);
        managementScope.Path = ManagementPath.DefaultPath;
        managementScope.Connect();


        ObjectQuery queryObj = new ObjectQuery(SoftwareQuery);
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(managementScope, queryObj);

        foreach (ManagementBaseObject managementObj in searcher.Get())
        {

           //get the software list here 

        }
```

**Note:** The above code is working on intranet properly

Please let me know anyone have solution on this.

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to the **Windows Management Instrumentation** service being in a stopped state. Take a look at [Starting and Stopping the WMI Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/starting-and-stopping-the-wmi-service).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Windows Management Instrumentation service is already running on VM